# Modeling this older style headlight?

Tags: modeling

This headlight is from a 67 Ford Mark IV, a LeMans racecar. It's the old style headlight of course with the ridges and so forth. I am not sure how to approach this, if you'd want to go with modeling it with geometry vs. trying to make some sort of bump map. What's the best approach? These are really the best pics I have.

[image]

Comment: Bump map/normal map. Modeling such a detail would be huge overkill.